# Why does the gcc compiler insert the version in data section?

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu

When i compile a c++ application with gcc, I noticed that gcc is inserting the gnu version string inside the rdata section.
How do i make gcc not to insert this?

[image]

Comment: XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? Or in other words, why does it matter?

Comment: @MatsPetersson, maybe to reduce binary size? Like a reason why we use `strip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use objcopy to edit the object file or you can remove the ident line from the assembler file that gcc can create before you assemble it.

Not that you'd ever need to.